# Beginner: Setting up React Gantt chart using google charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, gantt-chart

**Goal**: Display a gantt chart in react. Currently using Google Charts with a react wrapper from github. I'm still new to React and JS, I'm trying to learn!

**Problem**: Likely misunderstanding something critical I'm not aware of yet! I can't find the documentation/examples to help me get past this hump. I'm 90% sure I'm wrong with the syntax but after a few hours I still don't think I'm on the right track.

**Resources I'm using**:

[React google charts Gant example](https://rakannimer.github.io/react-google-charts/#/examples/Gantt?_k=prfqws) Trying to use the props window as a guideline

[^ The github readme from the above, specifically using the rows/columns setup](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts#initialize-using-rows-and-columns-)

[This older SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257461/cannot-render-two-of-the-same-react-component-specifically-react-google-chart/39745272#39745272)

**Code that's currently stuck on rendering**:

```
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';
import React from 'react';

class ExampleChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      rows: [
        ['Research','Find sources','2015-01-01T08:00:00.000Z','2015-01-05T08:00:00.000Z',null,100,null],
        ['Write','Write paper',null,'2015-01-09T08:00:00.000Z',259200000,25,'Research,Outline'],
        ['Cite','Create bibliography',null,'2015-01-07T08:00:00.000Z',86400000,20,'Research'],
        ['Complete','Hand in paper',null,'2015-01-10T08:00:00.000Z',86400000,0,'Cite,Write'],
        ['Outline','Outline paper',null,'2015-01-06T08:00:00.000Z',86400000,100,'Research'],
      ],

      columns: [
        {
          id:'Task ID',
          type:'string',
        },
        {
          id:'Task Name',
          type:'string',
        },
        {
          id:'Start Date',
          type:'date',
        },
        {
          id:'End Date',
          type:'date',
        },
        {
          id:'Duration',
          type:'number',
        },
        {
          id:'Percent Complete',
          type:'number',
        },
        {
          id:'Dependencies',
          type:'string',
        },
      ],
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Chart
             graph_id="ganttchart"
             chartType = "Gantt"
             columns={this.state.columns}
             rows={this.state.rows}
             chartPackages={['gantt']}
             width="100%" height="9999px">
         </Chart>
    );
  }
}
export default ExampleChart;
```

Answer (score 1):

react-google-charts seems to expect `Date` objects. I have not explicitly verified that in the source, but everything renders fine, when I change the `rows` to:

```
rows: [
    ['Research','Find sources',new Date(2015,1,1,8,0,0), new Date(2015,1,5,8,0,0),null,100,null],
    ['Write','Write paper',null,new Date(2015,1,9,12,0,0),259200000,25,'Research,Outline'],
    ['Cite','Create bibliography',null,new Date(2015,1,7,8,0,0),86400000,20,'Research'],
    ['Complete','Hand in paper',null,new Date(2015,1,10,8,0,0),86400000,0,'Cite,Write'],
    ['Outline','Outline paper',null,new Date(2015,1,6,8,0,0),86400000,100,'Research'],
],
```